# how do I stop click events happening in a eventDragDrop in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Basically the event has a url:   unfortunately this url is triggered after every drag/drop or re-size event. How can I trap this inside these functions and stop the url being retrieved? I only want the url to be used on an actual "click"  not a drag drop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `eventClick` callback and return false and stop propagation when you don't want the click to proceed.